# How can I make a java table where all rows can be used as keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

This is hard for me to explain as I'm not native to the English language, so I will try setting up an example.

I am trying to save some data about a player in a class called PlayerData. It has three variables with getters and setters.

```
public class PlayerData {

private String player;
private String username;
private UUID uuid;

public String getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public void setPlayer(String player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public UUID getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}
```

}

For each player in the game, there will be generated a PlayerData object. Normally I would store this in a Map, so I can get the data about a player from eg. the UUID. However, I could use a way to be able to use any variable in the PlayerData object as "key", so I don't require the UUID to get the PlayerData. A way to do this (and my usual approach) would be to have multiple maps, something like this.

```
Map<String, PlayerData> playerMap;
Map<String, PlayerData> usernameMap;
Map<UUID, PlayerData> uuidMap;
```

The problem is, when it scales up with multiple variables, this gets annoying, and perhaps even eats up the RAM? I'm not entirely sure, as it stores references.

It similar to SQL, where you can also get specific colums based on the content of the rows. That's what I'm looking for, but without the SQL database.

I made a table explanation below in an attempt to explain it further:

| Player | Username | UUID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | Peter1234 | 657f6c48-655f-11eb-ae93-0242ac130002 |
| Stephen | DogLover69 | 657f6efa-655f-11eb-ae93-0242ac130002 |
| Joshua | XxFlowerPotxX | 657f6fea-655f-11eb-ae93-0242ac130002 |

**Short edition**
I'm looking for a way to store multiple objects of the same type, where I (unlike Maps, that only take a single object as Key) can use multiple assigned variables as keys.

I hope the explaination was clear, I have absoloutly no idea how to explain it, which is probably also why I can't solve it by googling.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Unless you have a million or more PlayerData instances, just put them in a java.util.List and search the List linearly for the attribute you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, it's need to store various data for a specific user (and not just to update old values)

One way is through a custom map. Since only need a key (unique), could assume that username is doing that (eg:login). `MyData` can be customized further with what ever wanted to store.
Each key/username will contain a distinct list where new data is added.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class TestPData {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TestPData t = new TestPData();
        MyMap m = t.new MyMap();
        //key can be just user name, if unique is assured
        m.putMyData("player_1", t.new MyData("p1_data1"));
        m.putMyData("player_1", t.new MyData("p1_data2"));
        m.putMyData("player_2", t.new MyData("p2_data3"));
        m.putMyData("player_3", t.new MyData("p2_data4"));
        m.putMyData("player_3", t.new MyData("p2_data5"));
        m.putMyData("player_3", t.new MyData("p2_data6"));
        m.forEach((k,v)->{for(MyData d: v) {System.out.println(k+":"+d);}});
    }
    class MyData
    {
        String s;
        public MyData(String s)
        {
            this.s = s;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
    class MyMap extends HashMap<String, List<MyData>>
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void putMyData(String k, MyData d)
        {
            if(!this.containsKey(k))
            {
                this.put(k, new ArrayList<MyData>());
                this.get(k).add(d);
            }
            else
            {
                this.get(k).add(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
player_1:p1_data1
player_1:p1_data2
player_3:p2_data4
player_3:p2_data5
player_3:p2_data6
player_2:p2_data3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with few records (some thousands), you can use a list and iterative search as suggested by @gilbert-le-blanc, but if you need to manage huge amounts of records/attributes, it is better to use a database anyway. You can also use an in-memory database like Derby or H2.

- https://www.h2database.com/
- https://db.apache.org/derby/

With some effort you can create a custom collection with multi-indexed properties also, but it is not worth the pain.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map of maps, with the first mapping by the name of the property and the second map by its value.

In code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, PlayerData>> index = new HashMap<>();
```

To add a mapping:

```
PlayerData peterData = new PlayerData(
    "Peter", 
    "Peter1234", 
    "657f6c48-655f-11eb-ae93-0242ac130002");

index.computeIfAbsent("player", k -> new HashMap<>())
    .put("Peter", peterData);
index.computeIfAbsent("username", k -> new HashMap<>())
    .put("Peter1234", peterData);
index.computeIfAbsent("uuid", k -> new HashMap<>())
    .put("657f6c48-655f-11eb-ae93-0242ac130002", peterData);
```

This *navigates* to the different inner maps (one per indexed property) by means of the [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method, which creates an empty inner map and puts it into the outer map if it doesn't exist, or returns it if already present. Then, we add the mapping to the inner map by using `Map.put` as usual.

To remove a mapping:

```
index.computeIfAbsent("username", k -> new HashMap<>()).remove("Peter1234");
```

This is completely dynamic, as you don't have to change the data structure when you need to map by more properties. Instead, all you have to do is add mappings as needed.

The downside of this approach is that you'd need to use strings for the keys of the inner maps, but I think this is a reasonable trade-off.